# MassTransit: Specify a queue name in Request Client

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We have an application that communicates with a worker app via MassTransit on RabbitMQ. The worker/consumer configures itself like this (more or less, this is heavily simplified for clarity):

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
x.AddConsumer<Worker_Request>(typeof(Worker_Request_Definition));
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
{        
    cfg.Durable = false;
    cfg.AutoDelete = true;
    cfg.SetQueueArgument("x-expires", null);

    cfg.Host("<Address>", 5671, "/", h =>
    {
        h.UseSsl(s =>
        {
            s.CertificatePath = rabbitMqOptions.CurrentValue.CertificatePath;
            s.UseCertificateAsAuthenticationIdentity = true;
            s.ServerName = rabbitMqOptions.CurrentValue.ServerName;
            s.Protocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
            s.AllowPolicyErrors(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch);
            s.CertificatePassphrase = "";
        });
    });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(massTransitOptions.CurrentValue.QueueName, e =>
    {
        // Add the consumers here
        e.ConfigureConsumer<Worker_Request>(context);
    });
});
...
```

The app sending Worker_Requests configures itself like this:

```
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Durable = false;
        cfg.AutoDelete = true;
        cfg.SetQueueArgument("x-expires", null);

    });
    x.AddRequestClient<Worker_Request>();
...
```

And puts requests out like this (again, heavily simplified):

```
//_services is the injected IServiceProvider 
var requestClient = _services.GetService<IRequestClient<Worker_Request>>();
result = await requestClient.GetResponse<IResponse>(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token, timeout);
```

We're trying to specify queue names in the app so we can have multiple workers use a single RabbitMQ instance. The request client currently has an endpoint like "rabbitmqs:///?temporary=true"

Where in the application's configuration would I configure the queue name? I cannot for the life of me find this in docs where the Request Client model is used.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you changing the bus endpoint configuration, leave it alone. It will always be unique and remove itself after the bus shuts down. And I'm not sure what queue name you're trying to specify - the request's consumer queue name?

Comment: Thanks for the response- yes, we want to be able to have multiple workers on a single RabbitMQ instance that listen only on a queue named in their config files. Then run multiple instances of our application putting traffic on a specific queue through that single RabbitMQ instance based on their own config.

Comment: I still don't understand at all the question or what you're trying to do/why.

Comment: We want to support the following:

1 stage worker and 1 stage application,
1 dev worker and 1 dev application, 
and a single RabbitMQ instance (for cost reasons)

The stage worker would listen to a "stage" queue, dev on "dev" 

The stage app would send traffic to the stage queue, dev to dev

Right now, with the above configuration, either worker will pick up requests. I cannot see how to set queue names when configuring RabbitMQ/Mass Transit on the app with a queue name.

Comment: Something I think I missed while reading (and my apologies if I explained this poorly- I'm the dev supporting a previous dev's work). It seems that the Request/Response pattern's GetResponse always puts the messages in temporary queues. I don't see that it's possible to specify one, is it? I imagine you would be the person to know :).  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: The bus endpoint is used for responses, and the name should be unique which is why MassTransit generates the queue name dynamically. You can override it in the bus configuration, but I highly recommend _not_ doing that.